# Duplicate questions are helpful and shouldn't be closed as duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

Some questions are closed as duplicates but mostly when I search randomly, the duplicates that I find are helpful. So why are they closed as duplicates? Even when the question is edited, moderators don't pay attention even if the question wouldn't be a duplicate any more, still they leave them closed as duplicates.

Comment: Are you talking about the answers to the dupe-marked questions being helpful, or the questions themselves? How do they compare to the answers in the master question? And what do off-topic questions have to do with dupes?

Comment: I'm saying duplicates found when search for specific questions and they being helpful as they answered even duplicates and making sense. Wouldn't be worthless also when they being edited moderators don't paying attention if duplicates or off-topics.

Comment: "so why they put as duplicates?" umm... because they're... duplicates?

Comment: If you're referring to [your recent SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981087/java-puzzler-string-s-null-s-10), it's completely and thoroughly answered only at the given dupe master. I would not expect anyone with reopen privileges to do anything, because that's what a duplicate is.

Comment: I have edited my question now and I had have ask about if question is edited either duplicate or off-topic. Moderators don't pay attention and help with regrading questions. Just rush for putting on hold, off-topic and as unclear as put this one. No more attentions after edited, Being as it is as moderators do for the rest.

Comment: are you aware that if you [edit the closed question with explanation why it is not a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773) this will automatically put it into [reopen review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773) where experienced users will decide whether your explanation justifies reopening

Comment: Today when I searched at [Aviation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com) that how helicopters fly? I didn't get desired result so I asked one more [duplicate](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35270/how-does-a-helicopter-fly). May you should suggest better titles for good and master questions rather than worry about having duplicates in future. This feature must be remove and have other way to keep site free from duplicates. Either add feature that user could get what he wanted or improve searching feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duplicates are good *because they are marked as duplicates*, acting as a signpost to the other questions. See [How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Your implication that duplicate questions are a good thing but a question being *closed* as a duplicate is a bad thing is simply wrong. Without the question being closed there is no link between questions and you'd end your search on that question, limiting your chances on getting a good answer.

If you're unhappy with existing answers then there are other ways of bringing attention to existing questions; see [What should I do when there is a question that is the same as one I would ask but none of the answers answer my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134329/307988) and [What if my question is technically a duplicate, but the original question was never answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38547/307988) for example. Purposely asking a duplicate and complaining when it is closed as a duplicate isn't the way to go about it.

If a question is edited to a point where it isn't considered a duplicate, you can flag for moderator attention or ask a question on the sites meta to bring attention to this, make sure the question is significantly distinct though and explain your reasoning as best you can. If enough users with [sufficient privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) agree with you then the question will be reopened. It's also worth noting that generally speaking it is regular users — not moderators — that close and reopen questions.